# youtube iframe - phonegap - touching/tapping the red play button the video doesn't play

Tags: cordova, youtube

touching the red play button the video doesn't play, touching any where else on the video plays it.

I tested on IOS and Android using my phonegap app (though I'm sure it happens on regular browser as well)

This happens only with touch i.e. clicking with the mouse in the emulator doesn't reproduce the bug.

Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: the red play button works for me. is it about the restrictions for mobile environment that video playback has to be initiated by user activities? see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

Answer (score 0):

This code is a work around that create the iframe with the [youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and than in the onPlayerReady it set click handler to the red button that plays the video when clicked

Unfortunately it will break as soon as youtube change the class of the red button, lets hope they will solve this issue by then.

```
       patt = /www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?.*v=([^&]*)/;
                m = patt.exec(url);
                if (m != null && m.length == 2) {
                    url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + m[1] //+ "?autoplay=1"
                    console.log("url = " + url)


                    YTid = 'yt_'+m[1];
                    $("#mediaContentVideo").html(
                        "<div id='"+YTid+"'></div>"
                    ).after(function() {
                        player = new YT.Player(YTid, {
                          height: $(window).height()/2,
                          width: $(window).width()*0.95,
                          videoId: m[1],
                          events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                          }
                        });
                    })




                }
```

The HTML

```
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log("hey Im ready");
    $.each($('iframe'),function(i, iframe) {
      d=$(iframe).get(0).contentDocument

      $(".ytp-large-play-button",d).click(function() {
        player.playVideo();
      })
    });      
  }


</script>

    <div id="mediaContentVideo" >
    </div>
```